# Backbone app with CommonJS and Browserify

Tags: backbone.js, commonjs, browserify

I thinking of bringing my existing app over to using CommonJS modules and using Browserify to `bundle` up the modules into one file.

I'm getting my head around writing modules but the one thing I'm a little sceptical before I dive in and start re-writing certain bits, is how can I optimise it slightly so I don't have to include Backbone, Underscore, jQuery and any helper files in in each file, ie.

```
var Backbone = require('/backbone');
var $ = require('/jquery');
var _ = require('/underscore');
```

At the top of each file is going to get a little tedious after a while.

Being a complete CommonJS, Browserify n00b, I'm wondering if I'm missing something very obvious somewhere?

Comment: I think the other obvious thing besides the accepted answer is that most people *do* require modules where they're needed.  This is an important part of the require pattern, IMHO. Tedious perhaps, but it's more than boilerplate; it's plainly stating which other pieces of code a given module is dependent on and where that code resides, and helps to keep code modular and independent.  It's as far as possible from the classic PHP hell of grep'ing through files trying to find magical function definitions you know come from *somewhere*.

Comment: One of the very core principles of commonjs modules is that each explicitly label its dependencies. Saving key strokes, IMO, is NEVER a good reason to use a global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "very obvious thing" you're missing is that you can create globals in Node.js, and in the Browserify environment just the same. Either do it explicitly by using `global.Backbone = require('/backbone')`, or less explicit by just doing `Backbone = require('/backbone')` (without `var` in front).

Note that in the browser, the `global` object is in fact the `window` object. However, attaching to the `window` object would mean you lose compatibility with Node.js, because that typically doesn't have a  global variable `window` defined.

Comment: This is what I did. It feels a little bit wrong considering the fact that we're using tools like Browserify to manage dependencies, but it's really fine as long as you keep it nicely organised and limit your dependence on globals.

Comment: While theoretically correct, I downvoted because you shouldn't be encouraging using a global to save on key strokes. This answer breaks one of the core principles of the commonjs spec which is that each module should explicitly define its dependencies.